# Can´t write into state in componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problems to write some values that are received via nextProps in the componentWillReceiveProps() in the state of the component.

This is my current Code:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log("REV")
    console.log(nextProps)
    const dateFrom = nextProps.requestDateFrom;
    if(nextProps.requestDateFrom != 'undefined'){
        this.setState({
            dateFrom: dateFrom,
            dateTo: nextProps.requestDateTo
        });

        //console.log(nextProps.requestDateFrom)
        this.calculateDays();
    }

}

calculateDays(){
    console.log("clas")
    console.log(this.state.dateFrom)

}
```

I don´t understand why this does happen, because the data are in `nextProps` and also the const `dateFrom` is filled in `componentWillReceiveProps()`. But when I try to access them in the `calculateDays()`, the state is empty.

Of course, I could just pass the values as parameter´s to the function, but would prefer to have them in the state, so I can access them in other methods.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate _setState() does not immediately mutate this.state_

Comment: use `` around code, instead of '' to format code.

Comment: @BayLife can you put your logic into the `render` function? This will at least ensure correctness, in case the state never got updated on time.

Comment: @BayLife Could you attach an equivalent of `onUpdate` handler which adds the value to state?

Comment: @BayLife No, not calling a setState() within render. That's horrible. I am saying attach an event handler, something on the lines of `onUpdate` which you can attach to your component (you might have to create it yourself as it might not exist in your component).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read more about react's Lifecycle [Component Specs and Lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)

Calling this.setState() within componentWillReceiveProps will not trigger an additional render.

you can run the code below and see how it work.

With pleasure!

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super()
    this.state = {
      count: 0
      }
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps ) {
    console.log(nextProps)
    
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count ++ 
    })
    console.log('componentWillReceiveProps: ' + this.state.count) 
    // componentWillReceiveProps: 1
    // Calling this.setState() within this function will not trigger an additional render.
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.count) // still 0
    return (
      <h1>{this.props.content}, {this.state.count}</h1>
    )
  }
}

class Outer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super()
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      content: 'Hello, world! '
    }
  }
  handler() {
    this.setState({
      content: 'Hello Component\'s Props had Changed! '
      })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello {...this.state} />
        <a onClick={this.handler}>change the Hello </a>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Outer />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id='root'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the new lifecycle hook `getDerivedStateFromProps()` to shape the new state according to the props. Then you can call your `calculateDays` in `componentDidUpdate()` hook. For example:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    const dateFrom = props.requestDateFrom;
    if(props.requestDateFrom != 'undefined'){
        return {
            dateFrom: dateFrom,
            dateTo: props.requestDateTo
        };
     }
     return null;
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    this.calculateDays();
}
```